# How to make mediawiki understand different languages markup?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I wonder how can I make mediawiki parse markup tags in different languages? e.g I need to enable french language and give users ability to write [[Catégorie:Something]] instead of [[Categorie:Something]] or if enable russian be able to write [[Категория:Something]]

I have changed language in LocalSettings like this:

```
$wgLanguageCode = "fr";
$wgContLang = "fr";
```

and run rebuildall.php but nothing changes.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking about the ability to use markup in a language other than the content language (e.g. Russian markup on a French wiki): correct? Do you need to use multiple languages on this wiki, or just one (other than English)? Is the non-English and non-content-language a translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extend the [namespace aliases array](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgNamespaceAliases):

```
$wgNamespaceAliases['Catégori'] = NS_CATEGORY;
$wgNamespaceAliases['Категория'] = NS_CATEGORY;
```

However, this is only needed when you want to make *additional* aliases for a few namespaces. By default, the [namespace names are localized](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Localisation#Namespace_name_aliases) already, so that (next to the canonical English names) the namespaces are named according to your `$wgLanguageCode` setting. As @leo mentioned, this might need a cache clearing to become effective.

Comment: Further information is available on the [Manual page for $wgLanguageCode](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgLanguageCode). Note the part about how to clear the message cahce after changing $wgLanguageCode: `echo 'MessageCache::singleton()->clear()' | php maintenance/eval.php`

Comment: @leo: Yeah, I had suspected that this is in charge of setting the default namespace aliases, but I couldn't find evidence for it in the docs. Can you?

Comment: just browsing quickly, [it seems like it](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/Title_8php_source.html#l00832)

Comment: Aliases work great. Is there any list with all aliases which should be translated? Or maybe list of already translated list of aliases?

Comment: I think you should only create the few aliases which your users need, not all possible ones. However, yes, all of them are translated already, and can be viewed at https://git.wikimedia.org/tree/mediawiki%2Fcore.git/HEAD/languages%2Fmessages or https://translatewiki.net/w/i.php?module=namespace&title=Special%3AAdvancedTranslate